# Sidebar mini and max on toggle, how to test it using protractor

Tags: angular, protractor

I am trying to test a website built in Angular 2 using protractor & Jasmine. When I toggle a button the sidebar of the web app changes to a thinner one. It becomes normal when toggled again. How to test this in Protractor?

I am not what to write in expect to capture this or to test this.

The side bar, is identified by `div.sidebar-wrapper`
the change that happens when I toggle the button is that the body class changes from `<body class>` to `<body class = "sidebar-min">`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  theSwitch.togglebutton.click();
      expect(theSwitch.bodyclass.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
      });
```

here body class is a variable where the selector pointing to the mini sidebar